# How to install Laravel 4 offline

Tags: laravel-4, installation, offline

I am a newbie when it comes to Laravel 4.

I would like to ask if there is a way to install Laravel 4 without internet?
If there is a way to do this, can you include a link or a tutorial on how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> I would like to ask if there is a way to install Laravel 4 without internet?

Well you need The Internet to do the initial download of Laravel - but you can then move it to another computer that has no internet access:

1. Download the Laravel [framework from here](https://github.com/laravel/laravel) (either via git - or just 'download' the zip file) into your project folder.
2. Run composer install - which will grab all the associated vendor dependencies that Laravel needs to run.
3. Copy the entire 'project folder' (including the vendors directory) to another computer

You can read more about [Laravel installation from the official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/installation). Basically once you have it working - you can then just 'copy' it to whereever you need it.

Comment: This is an old post but I have the same question but about composer. When I run the installer, it requires internet connection. I have the `    .phar    ` file but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: @BenJunior - you cant run composer without an internet connection. You need to run composer on another computer first, then copy the files

Comment: Okay, Thanks I'll try